# YANG , Telemetry sensor path

Tags: python, cisco, telemetry, netconf, yang

i am using this module " Cisco-IOS-XR-pfi-im-cmd-oper.yang" to get interface counts (UP , Down , Admin-Down), but i am stuck with symbol *[] , i dont understand what to put inside if there is no keys inside list brackets ,

```
 +--ro node-type-sets
 |  +--ro node-type-set* []
 |     +--ro node-name?           xr:Node-id
 |     +--ro type-set-name?       Interface-type-set
 |     +--ro interface-summary
 |        +--ro interface-counts
 |        |  +--ro interface-count?              uint32
 |        |  +--ro up-interface-count?           uint32
 |        |  +--ro down-interface-count?         uint32
 |        |  +--ro admin-down-interface-count?   uint32
 |        +--ro interface-type* []
 |           +--ro interface-counts
 |           |  +--ro interface-count?              uint32
 |           |  +--ro up-interface-count?           uint32
 |           |  +--ro down-interface-count?         uint32
 |           |  +--ro admin-down-interface-count?   uint32
 |           +--ro interface-type-name?          string
 |           +--ro interface-type-description?   string
```

i figure out this path below  , but it still keep tell me is worng

```
Cisco-IOS-XR-pfi-im-cmd-oper:interfaces/node-type-sets/node-type-set[type-set-name='hardware-interfaces',node-name='0/RP0/CPU0']/interface-summary/interface-type[interface-type-name='IFT_GETHERNET',interface-type-description='GigabitEthernet']/interface-counts
```

i want to get "interface-counts" when the :

```
type-set-name='hardware-interfaces' 
node-name='0/RP0/CPU0' 
interface-type-name='IFT_GETHERNET' 
interface-type-description='GigabitEthernet'
```

all these info to get specific interface counts for this module

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual query you are trying to perform, or provide more context, so it is evident what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok , the question now edited

Comment: It is still unclear how you are requesting this data from the server. Are you performing a NETCONF `get`/`get-data` operation with a subtree/XPath filter? Or is this something else entirely?

Comment: I am using MDT telemetry , this path is the filter path inside the XR CISCO device configuration , this path came from YANG model called "Cisco-IOS-XR-pfi-im-cmd-oper.yang" , it is similar to Netconf or it is based on it , thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what context your path is used in, but I'm assuming you need an instance identifier.

If you need to uniquely identify an instance that is a list without keys or has list ancestors without keys (config false data nodes), you need to follow [RFC 7950, Section 9.13.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-9.13).

> The syntax for an instance-identifier is a subset of the XPath
> abbreviated syntax, formally defined by the rule
> "instance-identifier" in Section 14.  It is used to uniquely identify
> a node in the data tree.  Predicates are used only for specifying the
> values for the key nodes for list entries, a value of a leaf-list
> entry, **or a positional index for a list without keys**.  For
> identifying list entries with keys, each predicate consists of one
> equality test per key, and each key MUST have a corresponding
> predicate.  If a key is of type "empty", it is represented as a
> zero-length string ("").

There's an example in Section 9.13.4:

```
     /* instance-identifier for a list entry without keys */
     /ex:stats/ex:port[3]
```

Comment: i want to get "interface-counts" when the :
type-set-name='hardware-interfaces'
node-name='0/RP0/CPU0'
interface-type-name='IFT_GETHERNET'
interface-type-description='GigabitEthernet'

all these info to get specific interface counts for this module